# Probability Involving Combinations

Tags: probability

Problem: Three cards are selected at random from a group of 7. Two of the cards have been marked with winning numbers. What is the probability that at least 1 of  the 3 cards has a winning number?

The sample space is 35 from 7C5. 
The first problem was "What is  the probability that exactly 1 of the 3 cards has a winning number?" I did 2C1 X 5C2 / 35  and got the correct answer of 57%.

On this problem, I did (2C2 X 5C2) + (2C1 X 5C2) = 10 + 20 = 30. 30/35 is 85%.
The answer is supposed to be 71.4%. What did I do wrong, and how do I do this correctly? I don't really understand these "at least" problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least $1$ has a winning number is the complement of no card has a winning number.

Hence the probability is

$$1-\frac{\binom53}{\binom73}\approx 0.714$$

Your mistake is it should be

$$\frac{\binom{2}{2}\cdot \binom{5}{\color{red}1}+20}{35}\approx 0.714$$